# Can I convert a string to a resource location in C#?

Tags: c#, string, resources

Ok, beginner here just getting into learning programming, trying to make something in C#. Essentially, I have a string..

```
string resourcename = "example"
```

Conveniently enough, I also have a resource called example.jpg.. Now I'm trying to set my backgroundimage to example.jpg, using the string 'resourcename' instead of the actual filename.. 
Normally I'd do this:

```
this.BackgroundImage = namespace.Properties.Resources.example;
```

So now I'd like to do something like

```
this.BackgroundImage = namespace.Properties.Resources.resourcename;
```

Obviously, it doesn't recognize that because it's a string, so is there any way I can incorporate a string into the resource location?

Thanks! : D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the ideas from the two previous answers, you might try something like this:

```
BackgroundImage = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourcename));
```

Comment: For anyone who's interested, the reason I'm doing this is.. I'm using the MenuStrip to select the background image of a form.. So instead of creating a Click event for each MenuStripItem (currently 7 items) and setting the backgroundimage there, I now have 2 lines of code and it takes that information directly from the item name.

    string maplocation = ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Text;
    this.BackgroundImage = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(maplocation);

Answer (score -2):

```
string resourcename = "example"
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\m\Documents\...\" + resourcename + ".jpg" ) ;
```

Comment: This isn't what he's asking for... He's wondering if he can use the value of `resourcename` as a property of `namespace.Properties.Resources`, meaning if he did `namespace.Properties.Resources.resourcename` it would actually be `namespace.Properties.Resources.example`

Comment: example is a string in my example , and as long as images are in same folder , this works @DaveZych

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't _work_, I'm saying it doesn't answer his immediate question.