# How to set PictureBox's Image dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, textbox, picturebox

I am trying to use the Variable iconName to select and image from my resources; However I just can't get it to work.

To test if it comes out I change the button text to what the variable equals which is correct but the image won't change.

```
private void button_slctChamp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set variable to equal string from a textbox + _Square_0
        String iconName = textBox_slctChamp.Text + "_Square_0";

        // Test to see if iconName = "string" + "_Square_0"
        button_slctChamp.Text = iconName;
        // Which it does

        // Change Image of picturebox based on iconName
        pictureBox_champIcon.Image = Properties.Resources.iconName;
        // Never changes.........
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I convert a string to a resource location in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654693/can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-resource-location-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iconName` and `Properties.Resources.iconName` are two different values here. Also, `PictureBox.Image` property is of type `Image`, not `String`. So even if you did set it on the correct variable it would still not work.

If you want to get an image from a resource manager, do this instead:

```
pictureBox.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(iconName);
```

Comment: so in Properties.Resources.iconName it is looking for and image named iconName instead of the variable iconName?

Comment: ok, so i can understand this a little what is (Image) doing and also is the ResourceManager what lets me use the .GetObject?

Comment: (Image) is a cast of the value that will be returned by the GetObject method. If you need to know how ResourceManager works I suggest you have a look at the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help i will read through the doc's to understand it better.